# Canon 60D with SanDisk 32GB microSDHC Class 10 = Card Error

Tags: canon-60d, sdcard

I have a Canon EOS 60D ( firmware : v1.1.0 ) and a SanDisk Mobile Ultra 32GB microSDHC Class 10 with converter.

60D reported `Card Error`. I try to format with the camera as told, it said: `Cannot format, change card`.

Then, I try to format in my Mac with `Disk Utility` with FAT32 + MBR, it is read-write-able in Mac, but still, `Card Error` in 60D.

Then, I try to format in my Mac with `Disk Utility` with exFAT + GUID, it is read-write-able in Mac, but still, `Card Error` in 60D.

Then, I try to format in my Mac with `SD Formatter` with `Quick Format`, it is read-write-able in Mac, but still, `Card Error` in 60D.

Then, I try to format in my Mac with `SD Formatter` with `Quick Format` with `Logical Address Adjustment`, it is read-write-able in Mac, but still, `Card Error` in 60D.

**UPDATE** : I tried to use the card in an old Samsung compact digital camera PL80, it works, and it can be formatted. Strange, after I formatted the card with the camera, old files are still here and the photos are gone.

**UPDATE** : Double checked with Panasonic 128MB full size SD card & SanDisk 2GB full size SD card, work perfectly.

**UPDATE** : The SD lock is at `unlock` position. If I push it to `lock` position, 60D will report `Card is locked`.

**UPDATE** : Tried to format the card in Windows XP. It reported that the card only has 29.97GB capacity ( should be 31.xxGB ) and cannot be formatted with any disk format, including FAT32 and NTFS. It said, Windows is unable to complete formatting.

What should I do next ?

**CONCLUSION**

I took the card for replacement . The old one was proven faulty and the new one works fine . Thanks for everyone helping . ( Proved I was just in bad luck ... )

Comment: Have you tried another card in the camera to validate that the card is the problem, not the camera?

Comment: Tried another Panasonic 128MB full size SD card & SanDisk 2GB full size SD card , they work perfectly.

Comment: any chance the protection switch is on?

Comment: no, the SD lock is at `unlock` position. If I push it to `lock` position, 60D will report `Card is locked`.

Comment: Have you tried the microSD card in a different converter?

Comment: Why would you put any mbr on a memory card for a camera?  That's only used if you want to boot from the card.  Fast format usually just sets everything as erased, but leaves it there.  Long format gets rid of old content.  But neither of these should affect the camera's ability to read your card.

Comment: @StevenCunningham  Haven't tried another converter. Only one in my hand currently.

Comment: @Joe MBR ? Master Boot Record you mean ? I tried to format with `Quick Format` and non `Quick Format`. Still unable to complete formatting.

Comment: I don't do macs, so I don't know the details.  What you want is a long format (not quick format), preferably with no other options. If you have another card that works in your camera, see if it's fat32, or whatever exfat is and then use that to format the card in question.  MBR is master boot record which "theoretically" shouldn't bother anything, but why open the door to problems if you don't have to.

Comment: Other working cards are FAT32. Long format didn't work ( format failed ).

Comment: Have you tried to record videos in full HD? Im also curious if it works to use a micro SDHC card for the same reason as you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to be an issue with the card and compatibility. Doing a quick Google search some people are having compatibility issues along a range of devices. (Including but not limited to the Samsung Galaxy SIII [Micro SDHC 32GB Class 10 Card Problem](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=27562314))

A new firmware version 1.1.1 is now available for the 60D as of yesterday (06/19/12).

[Canon 60D Software Downloads](http://usa.canon.com/cusa/professional/products/professional_cameras/digital_slr_cameras/eos_60d#DriversAndSoftware)

Even though SD card compatibility is not listed as a feature of the update, sometimes there are changes not listed in the changelog. I would do the update and then go from there.

Can you return it and get a different card? May I ask your reasons for getting a MicroSD for your 60D?

Comment: Good to know that is a new firmware. I have returned the SD card for a new one, waiting for replacement. The reason of using microSD is to allow my Tablet to load the images from 60D, and upload to social network.