# Do I need to update nikonD3100 firmware to use a microSD 32GB HC1 card?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d3100, sdcard, microsd

On my nikon D3100, whenever I try to insert any microSD Sandisk32GB HC1 card with adapter, a green indicator light comes on and after some time it says the memory card is damaged and it can't use it. But, I can use this microsd on other cameras. Do I need to update my firmware? So far I 've tried:

1. Changed memory card, problem remains
2. Changed adapter, problem remains
3. Tried to copy firmware version to different sd card it's can't copying.

Does Nikon support sdcard HC1?

Comment: Does your camera work with a regular (non-micro, no adapter) SD card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your other question I gather that you currently have firmware version 1.01 installed.
The Nikon page on the [1.02 firmware version](https://nikoneurope-en.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/58931) does not mention anything about (micro)SD cards. It solely is a fix to optimize battery performance with certain batteries.

So no, updating your firmware should not be necessary to use the microSD card.

Comment: thanks...but could u please explain how to get rid of this problem....as per nikon approved sd card details it showed that sandisk 32gb hc card is not tested......thus, being really confused what to do...as i've tried lower storage sd card.......please help.....

Comment: i don't know how to get rid of your problem as I don't know what you have tried. Could you please ask a new question for this? Something along the lines of "Why is my microSD card not recognized by the D3100". Please include details such as what you have tried, what cards do work, if you can format the microSD in camera, etc... [Somebody](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/24448/9161) had a similar problem with his Canon. However there was no definite answer on how to fix it.